# DC.js - disabling brush also disables chart click events / crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

Disabling the brush on a bar chart seems to also disable the crossfilter between this chart and others. Clicking on the bars no longer results in filtering of other chart data.

What am I missing?

```
  bar
    .width(100)
    .height(100)
    .margins({top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5})
    .dimension(dim)
    .group(tot) 
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,10]))
    .centerBar(true)
    .brushOn(false)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .yAxisLabel("Amount") 
    .yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Nope - clicking the bars results in nothing happening. I added a click listener to verify the clicks are being registered & they are. Are there other considerations that would come into play to ensure that this chart is linked to all the others? Seems strange that all the charts would crossfilter except this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement bar selection by changing the scale to ordinal and adding xUnits:

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

Interestingly, this caused the bars to fall off center. This was fixed by *removing* the following:

```
.centerBar(true)
```